# Adding dynamic class to Webgrid column from model property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dynamic, webgrid

I have a Webgrid with with many coloumn.
One of the column is for due date.
I need to change each entries color depending upon condition.
Depending on condition i have added a color code property called "ColorCode" in view model.
This color can be "red","yellow" or "green".

my DueDate column looks like:

```
 taskgrid.Column("DueDate", "Due Date", style: "DueDate", canSort: true, format: (item) => item.DueDate.ToShortDateString()),
```

here this coloumn has class "DueDate".
I want to make it "DueDate red" , "DueDate yellow" or "DueDate green" 
from "item=>item.ColorCode"
i.e:

> style: "DueDate " + item=>item.ColorCode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WebGrid helper doesn't support this. A possible workaround is to apply the style not on the `<td>` but on the item inside:

```
taskgrid.Column(
    "DueDate", 
    "Due Date", 
    canSort: true, 
    format: 
        @<text>
            <div class="DueDate @item.ColorCode">
                @item.DueDate.ToShortDateString()
            </div>
        </text>
),
```

Other possible *hacks* involve using javascript to *move* the generated class from the inner `<div>` to the parent `<td>` if it's absolutely necessary for you to have this class applied on the `<td>`.

Answer (score 1):

The above code is modified as given below

```
taskgrid.Column("DueDate",header:"Due Date",format: @<text><div class="@((@item.Approved)?"reject-icon":"approve-icon")">@item.DueDate</div></text>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following: It works for me. I used conditional statement within class attribute.

```
class= "@((item.Approved)?"reject-icon":"approve-icon")"
```